# How to isolate the columns of a nested grid from the parent one?

Tags: html, css, css-grid

I have a parent grid with a dynamic size of 2 columns and a nested grid. I described the nested grid so that it would stretch across both columns of the parent grid.
My problem is that the elements of the first column of the nested grid affect the width of the column of the parent grid. How to avoid this?

```css
.body {
  width: 500px;
  margin-bottom: 50px;
}

.global_container {
  background: #3a3a3a50;
  display: grid;
  gap: 5px;
  grid-template-columns: min-content auto;
}

.row__elem_first,
.row__elem_second {
  min-width: 60px;
  height: 20px;
}

.row__elem_first {
  background: red;
}

.row__elem_second {
  background: green;
}

.sub_grid {
  display: grid;
  gap: 5px;
  grid-template-columns: min-content auto;
  grid-column-start: 1;
  grid-column-end: 3;
}

.sub_grid__row_elem_first,
.sub_grid__row_elem_second {
  height: 20px;
  min-width: 200px;
}

.sub_grid__row_elem_first.template2 {
  min-width: 20px;
}

.sub_grid__row_elem_first {
  background: blue;
}
.sub_grid__row_elem_second {
  background: orange;
}

.sub_grid__header {
  height: 20px;
  background: pink;
  grid-area: 1 / 1 / 2 / 3;
}
```

```html
<div class="body template1">
  <div class="global_container">
    <div class="row__elem_first"></div><div class="row__elem_second"></div>
    <div class="row__elem_first"></div><div class="row__elem_second"></div>
    <div class="row__elem_first"></div><div class="row__elem_second"></div>
  
    <div class="sub_grid">
      <div class="sub_grid__header"></div>
      <div class="sub_grid__row_elem_first"></div><div class="sub_grid__row_elem_second"></div>
      <div class="sub_grid__row_elem_first"></div><div class="sub_grid__row_elem_second"></div>
      
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="body template2">
  <div class="global_container">
    <div class="row__elem_first"></div><div class="row__elem_second"></div>
    <div class="row__elem_first"></div><div class="row__elem_second"></div>
    <div class="row__elem_first"></div><div class="row__elem_second"></div>
  
    <div class="sub_grid">
      <div class="sub_grid__header"></div>
      <div class="sub_grid__row_elem_first template2"></div><div class="sub_grid__row_elem_second"></div>
<!--       <div class="sub_grid__row_elem_first"></div><div class="sub_grid__row_elem_second"></div> -->
      
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

The code example (you can run it) demonstrates this problem (in template1, the nested grid elements have a minimum width of 200px, so the width of the first column of the PARENT grid takes the same value. In template2, I reduced the size of the nested grid elements to show that the first column of the parent grid has returned to its natural size).

Comment: You have two columns. The *primary* grid items in the first columns are set to `min-width: 60px`. The *nested* grid items are set to `min-width: 200px`. This sets the initial width of the first column to 200px. Your code works as written. If I'm missing something, perhaps make the question more clear.

Comment: @Michael Benjamin, Thanks for the answer, but you literally described what I described. This is my problem. I need the inner grid elements to not be taken into account when calculating the width of the outer grid columns

Comment: Yes. I understand. I was pointing out the logic. A column can't have multiple widths (otherwise, it's not a column). A column takes the width of the widest content item. If you don't want the width of the nested items to be taken into account, then what do you expect to happen with the `min-width: 200px`? This is why I asked you for more details.